# Number the bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, author-number

I created my bibliography style (author-year)  using biblatex. References are generated using biblatex and sorted alphabetically.

I have a question: How do I add numbering to references without changing the style of the citation from 'author-year' to "numbered"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It makes little sense to number an author-year bibliography if you still cite author-year. The numbers would just distract from the author-year label...

Comment: You could try ``style=numeric, citestyle=authoryear``. This would mean the citation is still in the (author, year) format, but that the bibliography includes numbers.